# centerVertical won't work with a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I made a simple fragment with two edit texts in it. Then, I tried to add an Image button. I want this fragment to be in the center of the activity and that worked fine. However, the Image button won't get in the center of the fragment below the two edit texts. Why won't centerVertical work with fragments?
Here is the xml code for the logIn view xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
<EditText
    android:hint="Type username"
    android:id="@+id/userNameText"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<EditText
    android:hint="Type Password"
    android:id="@+id/passwordText"
    android:layout_below="@id/userNameText"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 <ImageButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/login"
     android:onClick="onClick"
     android:id="@+id/logInBtn"
     android:layout_below="@id/passwordText"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

and the main xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.bazar.MainActivity">
<fragment 
android:name="com.example.bazar.LogIn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your fragment's layout params in the main.xml to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work, it gives an error:
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_content').@ChrisS

Comment: Sorry that was a copy/paste fubar on my part, changed to correctly read `match_parent`

Comment: that also didn't work, now the widgets have moved to the top left of the screen @ChrisS

Comment: Because you haven't specified any aligns for the elements in your logIn view xml so they are defaulting to the corners.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

change your login layout to this (this change will be made IN ADDITION TO what @ChrisS said):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
<EditText
    android:hint="Type username"
    android:id="@+id/userNameText"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<EditText
    android:hint="Type Password"
    android:id="@+id/passwordText"
    android:layout_below="@id/userNameText"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 <ImageButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/login"
     android:onClick="onClick"
     android:id="@+id/logInBtn"
     android:layout_below="@id/passwordText"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```